# Is there a way that this script, detects an error (like ErrImagePull) with the pod and when it does it fails?

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, sh

I have a script that checks the pods in a namespace and when all pods become ready it completes successfully.
What I need to do is to modify this script in a way that if it detects and error (like ErrImagePull) on the pod status it fails immediately.
The script works this way.
scriptname.sh 120 2 - which means that the script runs for 120 seconds and checks every 2 seconds.
If it detects the Ready status prior to 120 seconds it finishes,if not it stays 120 seconds and finishes.

This is the script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Copyright 2017, Z Lab Corporation. All rights reserved.
# Copyright 2017, Kubernetes scripts contributors
#
# For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
# file that was distributed with this source code.

set -e

function __is_pod_ready() {
  [[ "$(kubectl get po "$1" -o 'jsonpath={.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready")].status}')" == 'True' ]]
}

function __pods_ready() {
  local pod

  [[ "$#" == 0 ]] && return 0

  for pod in $pods; do
    __is_pod_ready "$pod" || return 1
  done

  return 0
}

function __wait-until-pods-ready() {
  local period interval i pods

  if [[ $# != 2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: wait-until-pods-ready PERIOD INTERVAL" >&2
    echo "" >&2
    echo "This script waits for all pods to be ready in the current namespace." >&2

    return 1
  fi

  period="$1"
  interval="$2"

  for ((i=0; i<$period; i+=$interval)); do
    pods="$(kubectl get po -o 'jsonpath={.items[*].metadata.name}')"
    if __pods_ready $pods; then
      return 0
    fi

    echo "Waiting for pods to be ready..."
    sleep "$interval"
  done

  echo "Waited for $period seconds, but all pods are not ready yet."
  return 1
}

__wait-until-pods-ready $@
# vim: ft=sh :
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kubectl get pods | awk 'NR > 1 && $3 != "Running" { $3=="ImagePullBackOff"?err=2:err=1;exit err }'
```

Most of the processing for this can most probably be achieved through awk. Pipe the output of the kubectl command and check for any lines other than the header (NR > 1) that are not equal to "Running". In these cases, check for the text "ImagePullBackOff". If it is found, exit with an error code of 2, else exit with an error of 1. In all other case, i.e. all pods running, awk will exit with 0.

If you want to check for additional errors, you can replace the ? conditional statement with an if statement and so:

```
kubectl get pods | awk 'NR > 1 && $3 != "Running" { if ($3=="ImagePullBackOff") { err=2 } if ($3 == "ErrImagePull") { err=2 } else { err=1 };exit err }'
```